# Am I able to play a free game on a PS Plus account that was downloaded from an ex-PS Plus account?

Tags: playstation-plus

I have a game I downloaded for free through a PS Plus account that no longer has the PS Plus membership.

If I were to subscribe to a new primary PS Plus account, would I still be able to play the game or re-download if in the event I delete the game?

Answer (score 3):

No, you will not be able to play your downloaded games. Any free games you downloaded will be unavailable once your membership has ended, since they are linked to that account.

[What happens when your PlayStation Plus membership is cancelled?](https://www.playstation.com/en-au/get-help/help-library/playstation-plus/information---benefits/what-happens-when-your-playstation-plus-membership-is-cancelled/)

> Once your PlayStation Plus membership ends, content you previously downloaded at no cost as part of the membership (such as Plus Monthly Games) will no longer be available. However, free avatars and content you purchased at a discounted PlayStation Plus price is yours to keep.
>
> If your PlayStation Plus membership expires and you renew it at a later date, you will regain access to content that you have previously downloaded through PlayStation Plus.

Comment: Is your answer based off experience or just reading their FAQ? Ive asked friends about this, before, and rhey tell me that despite sony officially saying "no, it wont work", it has, for them.

Comment: @Timelord64 I have not done this myself, but contrare I've had a friend who did this and it did not work. There is a part in the article that says if they cancel the subscription, they may play the games up until their membership expires. That may be the case

Comment: hi, thanks for your responses. just for the record, now that my shared account friend has renewed his plus account i noticed that all my plus games are no longer locked. didnt try to play them, but a download from his account the rocket league and could play it with my delorean dlc